# Aho-Corasick-like algorithm for use in anti-malware code

Tags: c++, algorithm, antivirus, aho-corasick

Is there an algorithm like [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), which can match a set of patterns simultaneously and is applicable to be used in anti-malware comparison? Do all known commercial antivirus software use the Aho-Corasick algorithm?

What are the advantages of the Aho-Corasick algorithm over [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)?

Comment: Keep in mind most commercial Anti Malware tools probably use something more than just exact string matching, in which case neither algorithm is the right answer.

Comment: Yes, I mean the standard comparison process without Heuristic & AI Techniques.

Comment: But Aho-Corasick, being a finite-state method, can be extended to fuzzy matching with some basic automata theory. Determining how to weight the dictionary is the hard part.

Comment: @larsmans Do you have references about how it can be extended  to fuzzy matching? Do you know about `ClamAV` if it extended the algorithm?

Comment: @Adban: Aho-Corasick constructs a finite-state machine on which the entire algebra of FA operations applies. The references that come to mind are Kornai's *Extended finite state models of language*, Mehryar Mohri's papers and Jurafsky & Martin's *Speech and Language Processing*, first few chapters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Boyer-Moore**: For searching one string in another target string
**Aho-Corasick**: For searching multiple patterns simultaneously

So the advantage being that Aho-Corasick is optimal if you want to search lot of patterns simultaneously in one pass.

[Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) string search can also match multiple patterns.

Comment: Is it commonly believed that Aho Corasick is optimal? I mean surely it is if you only do one query, but if you do many, might there not be a more efficient datastructure?